# How to change the button color in bootbox.alert

Tags: angularjs, bootbox

I am using `bootbox.alert`. Here i am getting `OK` button with blue color.

I want the `OK` button with orange color. I tried so many ways. Can you please suggest me.

This is my code.

```
bootbox.alert({
     message : "Error in task",
     closeButton: false,
     button : {
        ok : {
          label : "OK",
          className : "btn-orange",
          callback: function () {

          }
       }
     }
});
```

Comment: Can you please give response ASSP.

Comment: Is the issue is solved?

Comment: Ya..Its resoved..Thank q So much

Answer (score 4):

Can you try the below code:

```
bootbox.dialog({
    message: "Error in task",
    closeButton: false,
    buttons: {
        "success": {
           label: "Ok",
           className: "btn-orange",
           callback: function () {}
        }
    }       
});
```

**Update**

The below option is using with `dialog`, so no need to set `closeButton` and you can use the `danger` class to show in orange color.

```
bootbox.dialog("Error in task", {
    "label" : "Ok",
    "class" : "danger",   // or primary, or success, or nothing at all
    "callback": function() {
        //console.log("great success");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can using CSS

```
<style>
     .bootbox-alert div div div button.btn-primary{
         background-color: orange
     }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me with bootbox.js 5.4.0:

```
bootbox.dialog({
    message: 'Your Message',
    buttons: {
        ok: {
            label: 'OK', 
            className: 'btn-danger'
        }
    }
});
```

This provides a basic alert with a red button instead of the default blue one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Sameera Prasad Jayasinghe pointed me to right direction and allows in a very elegant way for several variants of formatting. E.g. if you would like to have a background color, filling the whole alertbox, you would specify:

```html
.bootbox-alalert div div {
    background-color: red;
}
```